# What is code equivalent of XAML to preserve whitespace?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, whitespace

What is c# code equivalent of following XAML, where I have a RichTextBox and I have selected Paragraph, and I want to enable/disable white space on this paragraph. In XAML I know how to enable, but I need to do this in code.

```
<Paragraph xml:space=\"preserve\">     Tabbed Code</Paragraph>
```

There is an equivalent I have found and its here,

```
void EnableWhiteSpace(Paragraph p, bool enable = true){
   if(enable){
         System.Windows.Markup.XmlAttributeProperties
              .SetXmlSpace(this.Document, "preserve");
   }
   else{
         System.Windows.Markup.XmlAttributeProperties
              .SetXmlSpace(this.Document, "default");
   }
}
```

This is still not working !!! I am not getting tabs !!...

Here is my problem, I have a RichTextBox which is used to edit code and which does syntax highlighting. Everything is fine except when I call following I see no tabs in my code.

```
 TextRange tr = new TextRange(
                         myRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart,
                         myRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
 string text = tr.Text;
```

The text that I receive contains no tabs, so I thought enabling whitespace on every paragraph before doing text range might give me tabs.

UPDATE

I tried navigating every inlines (run) in the paragraph, none contains tab, I am just loosing all the tabs :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RichTextBox is buggy, it will just ignore all tabs, however its problem of WPF itself and cant be fixed without doing complex workarounds.

Alernative is to write your own FlowDocument to text converter, however this is very complex as nodes do not directly give any line or tag information.

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent. The XML option `xml:space="preserve"` is valid only for *interpreting* XML files (in your case, XAML, which is a kind of XML), and has no meaning in C# as there are no XML files involved.

The C# equivalent of your XAML code would be following:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.Inlines.Add(new Run("     Tabbed Code"));
```

Comment: Well I have RichTextBox and I have enabled "AllowTabs" property, when I edit some text in it, and I retrive TextRange(for entire thing).Text, I do not see tabs, new lines are fine but I see unindented text.

Comment: @Akash: `xml:space` has a meaning only during interpreting of the XAML file. So your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Please read my update, basically I am loosing tabs after I have edited the document in RichTextBox.

Comment: Well, maybe you can read the collection of `Inlines` one by one?

Comment: I will try and let you know in few minutes.

Comment: I have found the equivalent, please check my answer, however it is still not working.

Comment: I found that despiter AcceptTabs being on it ignores tabs at the start of lines but not at the end.  e.g. if the user types "s" then tabs the Text property contains the tab.  If they start with a tab it ignores it.  Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @Alan: no, I didn't encounter this problem :(